# not getting the proper output in number format

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I am formating numbers in `locale US`. The problem i am facing is that it's not displaying the exact number user gives rather it's displaying upto 8 digit number.

In the childview it shows the user input but when i try to display it i n the groupview it's displaying only 8 digits
 [image]
Code:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat= NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
numberFormat.format(double);// double is the user given input
```

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile. Show us real, complete code reproducing the issue.

Comment: check what it's displaying?? are those the same value??

Comment: Additionally, for currency values you should probably be using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Also log the double directly before formatting to make sure the value is what you expect it is.

Comment: it was working before but not now

Comment: the value is exactly what should be

Comment: Can you then also log `numberFormat.getMaximumIntegerDigits()`?

Comment: `2000000000` this is what i got

Comment: Ok, one more thing, log the string that `format()` produces. This all seems to work fine for me.

Comment: it's giving `1.2121212E13`

Comment: Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the entire code, I can't reproduce what you claim here, the issue might be in a part of the code you're not posting. Also creating the MCVE might help you find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `double` cannot hold so many significant digits (mantissa). You should use `BigDecimal` here otherwise you can always lose precision.

Comment: I'm not the one who down voted, but probably because it's not true. Double can easily hold enough digits for the example in the question. While it might still be a good idea to use BigDecimal in this case, the explanation isn't correct.