# Android Number Format Output?

Tags: java, android

i'm learn Java thourgh Android Studio with Java, i was stuck at the Float Format, how can you display, for example: **1.234E10** instead of 12340000000000, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`12340000000000` is actually `1.234E13`

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
String format = formatter.format(12340000000000.0);
System.out.println(format);
```

Output:

```
1.234E13
```

Comment: sir, what if i want the inverse of the following how could i achieve that?

Comment: @Virus use a non-scientific `NumberFormat` pattern, e.g.  `0.0`

Comment: sorry sir i didn't understand, I am struggling with this problem as I'm trying to sum up a complete column from a database table and it will give the value like  `1.234E13` where i want the other one.. sir it will be very helpful if you can help me . Thank you

Comment: Post a new question with all the details of the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986358/why-java-numberformat-displaying-only-8-digits-after-formating/29987005#29987005  here is the question

Answer (score 0):

`1.234E10` is actually the same as `12340000000000` only it's printed out in an engineering format and it's a hell of a lot more readable than `12340000000000`.